# Are questions concerning the dynamics of clubs and projects on-topic for The Workplace?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-definition, questions

I'd like to ask a question about interpersonal relations in a school robotics team. As far as I can tell, this:

- Represents a group dynamic
- Simulates (or creates somewhat of an analog for) a professional environment
- It is a workplace, though not an official one

Is this category of question appropriate for The Workplace?

Comment: I Think it will depend on what the specific question is.  Is it ok to exclude the stinky kid from our team is not on topic.  Some other topics will be.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18/should-we-allow-school-college-related-questions/20#20) covered a broader case of schooling-related questions.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the question is about graduate students, you may or may not have better luck at [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I've never participated there; I just know it exists. :)

However, we have had students ask questions here before about problems faced while working on a project.  I assume your question is on professionalism and regarding a professionalism problem. If that's the case, your question could work assuming you remain concise, objective, and write your question in Q&A format so that there's an actual question for users to definitively answer.

Before posting, take a look around the site at up-voted questions to get a feel for things. Here's an example of a good question with a slight academic twist that's related to resume writing:  [How to describe my position in course projects?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13765/how-to-describe-my-position-in-course-projects)

Here's another one that involves a group project at a University: [How do I eliminate a coworker from a project?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/how-do-i-eliminate-a-coworker-from-a-project).  If this answers your question, then awesome! If it doesn't and you end up posting, be sure to make it clear how your problem differs, which will help avoid your question being marked as a duplicate.

Hope this helps!